# Disconnect user from game center

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm using GameCenterManager from Apple and I would like to know if there's a way to disconnect a game center authenticated user...

Comment: Just curious, but what could be the reason that you would want to do that?

Comment: If someone else want to play ? :)

Comment: I see =) Well I'd say it's just not meant to work that way...

Comment: Yes I'm using urlscheme to make it as right as possible ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple documentation says that,

> After authenticating their account on a device, that player remains
>   connected on that device, even when the player switches to other
>   applications or reboots the device. A player only disconnects from
>   Game Center only by launching the Game Center application and
>   explicitly signing out.

See :  [Apple Doc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html)

So I guess no, User must switch to Game Centre and disconnect their self from there.

---

**Potential reason** : Game centre serves to all game apps which supports game centre feature. So, it's better to centralise a gamer's id. Same id for all different games. Now in order to do that they must authenticate gamer from one gaming device and maintain the id in all other application as well.

Now, if you explicitly disconnect from game centre from your app, the user will get confuse when he/she goes to another app and try to upload the score.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on settings. Them click privacy and look to see the game centre icon. The rest is self explanitory. Just choose that choice and block the Game Center. Sple